# How to control mouse using Android sensors ?

Tags: java, android

I have done the client socket and server socket things. I need to use the gravity sensors data to move my PC's mouse. How can i access the mouse from my java code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the Robot class here (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) It provides you with a method called `mouseMove(int x, int y);`that does exactly as you wish.

Working code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.mouseMove(300, 550);
 }
```

Now to get the 'Gravity sensors' you speak of, you're most likely going to want to look up a tutorial on how to use the `VelocityTracker` provided by Android.

Example:
https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/movement.html

Answer (score 2):

You can control the mouse cursor using a Java object called `Robot`. Declare your robot:

```
Robot r = new Robot();
```

Using data from your sensor, you can move the mouse to specific coordinates on the screen (with x= 0 and y= 0 at the top left corner of the screen) like this:

```
r.mouseMove(x, y);
```

You can also click the mouse like this:

```
r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK); // for button 1
r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```

You must surround your code in a try/catch block for an `AWTException`:

```
try {
    Robot r = new Robot();
    // functions go here
} catch (AWTException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```